# How to set Image size according to VisualState inside UserControl used by DataTemplate

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, uwp

I want to change size of images inside UserControl that is used by DataTemplate of GridView. So far I can't get this to work.

I found this [link](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2015/05/12/adaptive-triggers-relativepanel-and-datatemplate-in-universal-windows-platform/) from Macro Minerwa blog that only way to use adaptive trigers inside DataTemplate you need to use UserControl, I changed my xaml code that way but still no success.

This is my GridView:

```
<Grid  Grid.Row="1" >

        <Grid Margin="10">
            <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfApps}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <ItemsWrapGrid x:Uid="WarpGrid" Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="5" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <userControls:AppList/>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

This is my UserControl:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="RemoteController.Views.UserControls.AppList"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:RemoteController.Views.UserControls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
>

<Button x:Name="AppButton" Command="{Binding DataContext.SendPilotCommand, ElementName=AppListPageGrid}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" Padding="0" Margin="0" >
    <StackPanel Background="AliceBlue">
        <Image x:Name="AppImage"  Source="{Binding GridImg_url}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>


<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
        <VisualState x:Name="Small320">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="320"/>
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="AppButton.MaxHeight" Value="43"/>
                <Setter Target="AppButton.MaxWidth" Value="72.5"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Large1024">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1024"/>
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="AppButton.MaxHeight" Value="172"/>
                <Setter Target="AppButton.MaxWidth" Value="290"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Like I wrote before I want to set Image size according screen size.

Comment: Can you try adding the <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups> node inside the Button called AppButton?

Comment: @igrali Will try that.

Comment: @igrali Yes that helped, I moved them inside button, could you explain why it wasn't working on a UserControl level?

Comment: Hi, I got the same problem, Its the limitation of VisualState at the moments.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom image control that checks the window size and based on the size I will add a prefix for the size this usually works